How would increasing atomic bond strength affect nuclear physics?
I'm writing a magic system, and one of its types directly affects the atomic bonds of materials. What mages can do is increase the amount of energy required to break or create those bonds. How would doing so change the behaviour of those materials being used for fusion/fission?
One addendum; there are other kinds of magic that allow for nuclear reactions to happen instantly, i.e. no chain neutron reaction necessary. As a result, the question is just about activation energy and release, but I'm interested in how this would change the reaction in question. If this ends up complicating the issue, though, just assume the mage in question got their hands on some uranium-235.

Metals such as uranium or thorium or plutonium are not made of molecules. There are no molecular bonds in a piece of metal.

Did you you mean to ask about Strong Force (holding protons & neutrons together in the atoms nucleus) or the atomic bond (holding atoms together in the molecule)?

@Rabbi I was asking about atomic bonds, but it's been made clear that those don't affect fusion/fission all that much. Although, the question of strong force might have been better for the kind of answer I was going for.

It wouldn't change much
In chemistry molecular bonds are defined as covalent bonds. However, Uranium is a metal and generally only forms ionic bonds, the most common being Uranium Oxide (several oxidation states exist, but they're all still ionic bonds).
Making this sort of change won't really affect the Uranium or its nuclear chemistry at all. As molecular bonds just don't play a part in nuclear chemistry.
If you mean to include Ionic bonds in the list of what is strengthened (even though it's not a molecular bond), increasing the bond strength would decrease the distance between the ions, and could potentially increase the density of the material. Since the critical mass is inversely proportional to the square of the density you would need less fissile material to get a spontaneous chain reaction, but if you're handwaving this issue away, then it probably doesn't matter at all.

It depends on how the magic works. AFAICT there are two ways of changing the strength of the bounds:

increase the electron mass by increasing the vev of the Higgs field
increase the electron mass by increasing coupling to the Higgs field
increase the strength of the electromagnetic force

And each of those things will have some impact on the decay properties of some atoms.
The rate of the electron capture decay will be increased by bringing the electron closer and making it heavier. The beta decay rate would also be affected, with the possibility of some new beta minus decays that were otherwise impossible due to decay energy lower than the elector mass. Some of those decays have energies of a couple of MeVs so this would be a significant effect.
Increasing the Higgs VeV would decrease the rate of Beta decay by making the W bozons heavier.
Increasing the strength of the electromagnetic force would have the biggest effect. This would make heavier elements less stable because they have a lot of protons very close to each other. Even a small increase might have made some uranium isotopes very unstable.
Additionally making the bound stronger might make some materials denser and decrease the critical mass.

It won't change anything.
Molecular bonds have energies in the order of eV or lower, while nuclear bonds have energies in the order of MeV, 1 million times higher.
